# QGIS fails to open REST Service

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, wfs, arcgis-rest-api

I'm using QGIS 2.18.10. I want to open the following WFS into QGIS:

http://www.geoportal.lt/inspire-services/rest/services/INSPIRE/Transport_networks_CommonTransportElements/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service

Found on: https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/en/dataset/464351d4-ca15-4e7a-8f00-61287a47f38b/resource/2089fa44-17cf-49f4-97bf-0710a9d241fc

I downloaded and installed the ArcGIS REST API Connector, but I don't know what kind of information they want in the box 'Filter'.

As it's a WFS I tried to open the file with the regular 'Add WFS Layer' in the layer toolbox, but I get an error: unexpected end of file.

I found a lot of data like this (REST Service), but I'm wondering what's going wrong. Or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is **NOT a WFS**, but an ArcGIS REST service! QGIS comes with support for that built-in nowadays.

Use the Layer menu: `Layers` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add ArcGIS Mapserver Layer` and use this URL http://www.geoportal.lt/inspire-services/rest/services/INSPIRE/Transport_networks_CommonTransportElements/MapServer

Then it *should*™ work. For me it loads and loads so far, no image yet.

Comment: It is strange, becuase it clearly says 'Road transport network for INSPIRE download (WFS)' on the website I provided. However, I am new with ArcGIS REST services, does this mean it's more like a WMS? Edit: My goal is to save and work with the data. Therefore, it would be in my advantage if the data where more like a WFS

Comment: From my understanding an ArcGis Rest MapServer is like a WMS, while a FeatureServer would be like a WFS. Unfortunately the server in question only seems to list MapServer layers: http://www.geoportal.lt/inspire-services/rest/services/INSPIRE

Comment: Thats what I thought. Unfortunately, I am looking for vector data, not raster. Also, there seems to be a network request time out. So I haven't seen any images yet. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The  `InspireFeatureDownload` and   `InspirePredefinedDatasetDownload` listed as supported extensions on http://www.geoportal.lt/inspire-services/rest/services/INSPIRE/Transport_networks_CommonTransportElements/MapServer does suggest some vector download should be possible.

The ArcGIS documentation on creating such services [Create the feature download service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/inspire/latest/inspire-services/create-the-feature-download-service.htm) tells us that indeed it is/should be a WFS 2.0.0.

There is a section `Enable direct access` that tells us:

> This option enables the ability to access data directly through the standard WFS 2.0.0 getFeature operation without going through the stored query configured by the administrator. This option is disabled by default.

**So it possible that the service has not been configured as direct access.**

The page [Use the INSPIRE Feature Download service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/inspire/latest/inspire-services/use-the-inspire-feature-download-service.htm) suggests to us that the following URL should respond as a WFS

http://www.geoportal.lt/inspire-services/rest/services/INSPIRE/Transport_networks_CommonTransportElements/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS

but it doesn't...

I get a form, but it should be an XML response.  It would probably be worth contacting the data providers directly to check if this is intentional.

Comment: I contacted the provider and they stated that 'the WFS services aren't working properly at the moment'. There are, however, some predefined downloads on the website, but not the ones I am looking for. Thank you for your help.